# How many threads are allocated to event bus in a single vertx instance?

Tags: vert.x

I have some questions which are not clearly documented online, could you please help? Thanks.

How many threads are allocated to event bus in a single vertx instance? Is it configurable?

What is the execution model of event bus?

Comment: event bus runs in a single thread, that's the whole purpose of the excersize. There used to be a multi-threaded EB, but it was deprecated in the mid of ver. 3

Comment: Thanks. shall we go a step further and with more details? As debugging the source codes, I find in vertx standalone mode, there seem no dedicated thread for event bus, the publisher event loop directly schedules an event on subscriber event loop by calling on the context of subscriber event loop. So do you mean in vertx cluster mode, there is only one dedicated thread for event bus? or only a single thread in certain thread pool but only single thread at any time?

Answer (score 0):

> A Vert.x instance maintains N event loop threads (where N by default is core*2) by default

From the [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_verticles), by default a single instance of vert.x maintains multiple loop threads, which is configurable.

It can be configured with the `setEventLoopPoolSize(int eventLoopPoolSize)` method of `VertxOptions`, at deployment.

**Useful Documentation:**

[DEFAULT_EVENT_LOOP_POOL_SIZE](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/VertxOptions.html#DEFAULT_EVENT_LOOP_POOL_SIZE)

> public static final int DEFAULT_EVENT_LOOP_POOL_SIZE
> The default number of event loop threads to be used = 2 * number of cores on the machine

[setEventLoopPoolSize](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/VertxOptions.html#setEventLoopPoolSize-int-)

> public VertxOptions setEventLoopPoolSize(int eventLoopPoolSize)
> Set the number of event loop threads to be used by the Vert.x instance.